# use Xamarin.OAuth for my custom server with soap methods

Tags: android, xamarin, soap, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an ASP server that contains methods like login or send some people data to my Xamarin Android app with soap and WebReference.FN methods.

Now I want to have OAuth authentication in my communicates.
Is it possible to use Xamarin.OAuth for this or I should write my own class for the oath?

Comment: Does your ASP code on your server support OAuth2?

Comment: @SushiHangover not yet but I'll add it. I know the basics but xamarin.oauth is a little confusing.

Comment: If you are providing OAuth2 on your server, then yes you can use `Xamarin.Auth` (it provides a standard OAuth2 client interface...)

Comment: @SushiHangover So can I get token and keep it for next requests and also send username and password to the server with xamarin.oauth?

Comment: get/save save token|refresh-token, of course. user/pwd, since it is your OAuth2 server, yes, in an Username-Password OAuth authentication flow the OAuth2 server receives the user/pwd.